# My web can't display the firebase Realtime database data

Tags: html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have follow the youtube way to connect my web with the database I created in firebase but it won't work.

Below is my code in html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="banner.jpg"/>
    <h1 id="Result">testing</h1>

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.4/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script>
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "AIxcSyAV9E8ubLcEhJE9MNXFNRTli3vdiLAyqmM",
        authDomain: "python-com-firebase.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://python-com-firebase.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "python-com-firebase",
        storageBucket: "python-com-firebase.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "624398273473",
        appId: "1:624398273473:web:89b9c4ff9c9d85c3"
    };
    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the code of the index.js

```
window.alert('test');

var fireResult = document.getByElementById("Result");

var dbRef = firebase.database().ref().child("ParkingSeat");

dbRef.on('value', function(datasnapshot){
    fireResult.innerText = datasnapshot.val();
});
```

My web can run the index.js script as I enter my web the alert window will popup. But the data still didnt change.

Answer (score 0):

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize .

※Click `From the CDN` tab.

```
//.....
<!-- Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.4/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- Add Firebase products that you want to use -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.4/firebase-database.js">
<script>
//....
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add index.js script below the initialization of Firebase, like this code

```
<body>
    <img src="banner.jpg"/>
    <h1 id="Result">testing</h1>

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.4/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script>
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "AIxcSyAV9E8ubLcEhJE9MNXFNRTli3vdiLAyqmM",
        authDomain: "python-com-firebase.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://python-com-firebase.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "python-com-firebase",
        storageBucket: "python-com-firebase.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "624398273473",
        appId: "1:624398273473:web:89b9c4ff9c9d85c3"
    };
    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    </script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

you have to remove `<script src="index.js"></script>`from head section